# Kernel compiling changes

Tags: c, linux, compilation, kernel

I'm trying to experiment changes in the `open.c` file (more specifically the system calls `open()` and `close()`)
Every time I change the code in the `open.c` file, I recompile the kernel using

```
make -j4 deb-pkg
```

But I'm experiencing that, even if I changed the code, and in the make-output appears the compilation of open.o my modifications are not in the installed kernel, I have to `make clean` and `make -j4 deb-pkg`.
But doing so, the compilation is more time consuming.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you tried just using `make bzImage` and placing your image manually to `/boot`? It normally worked for me. You can still build a package once you're happy with your changes.

Comment: Do you think this solves the problem? I read that also with `make bzImage` you have to `make clean` before a `make bzImage`. The issue is that makes should keep trace of the modified files :(

Comment: the kernel buildsystem is far from perfect, so if something goes wrong -> `make clean`. In my experience, just changing a single source file is picked up quite well without a clean rebuild. Just test it...

Comment: Ok, in  /boot I have `vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic`, `vmlinuz-3.16.7-ckt14`, `vmlinuz-3.16.7-ckt14+` with the relative System.map how can I know which is the one loaded?
`uname -r` returns me `3.16.7-ckt14+`